# Axis label bigger than plot output in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

How can I get the full axis label without extending the plot itself?
[image]

```
sixdez<-data.frame(outTemp3=c(-5.0, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.0, -4.5, -4.0, -4.0, -3.5),
                   hour=c("18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00"))



p2<-ggplot(sixdez, (aes(hour, outTemp3, group=1)))+geom_line(colour="blue", size=3, linetype="dashed" )+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = levels(sixdez$hour)[c(F, rep(T, 1))])+ylab("Ambient Temperature °C\n")+xlab("time of day")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA),plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", colour = NA), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size=2),panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=65, face="bold"),axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=+0.6,size=65, angle=45),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=65,face="bold", colour="blue"), axis.title.x =element_text(size=55, face="bold"), 
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 2),axis.ticks.length=unit(.25, "cm"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-7.5,5,2.5), limits=c(-7.5,5),position = "right")
png('plot2.1vl08Ta.jpg', width = 1380, height = 850, units = "px", bg = "transparent")
print(p2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: What do you specifically want as a result? Do you not want to just use a line break in your ylab? Or decrease the text size?

Comment: It is for a poster I already decreased the size but it is to small than and I can't use a line break because it is taking to much space. So my label has to bigger then the axis line itself what is no problem because I have enough space upwards. The plot is later merged with a second one.